# Unable to show the indexed content in Solr 5.0

Tags: solr

The content field is unable to be shown during searching, even though the following line has been added to the schema using curl from the resource named in `managedSchemaResourceName`.

`<field name="content" stored="true" type="text_general" indexed="true"/>`

I'm using the schema from `ManagedIndexSchemaFactory`.

As the `ExtractRequestHandler` has already been defined in `solrconfig.xml` by default, and I'm using the `ManagedIndexSchemaFactory`. I have added the content field line to allow the indexed content to be shown when user does a query, as the default setting is not for the content to be shown. I added in using `curl` as follows:

```
$ curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
"update-field" :

{ "name":"text", "type":"text_general", "stored":true, "indexed":true, "storeOffsetsWithPositions":true}

}' http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/schema
```

I have indexed the document using the following command:
`java -Dc=collection1 -Dauto=true -jar example\exampledocs\post.jar example\exampledcos\solr-word.pdf`.

The document is successfully indexed, and when I does a search of any words from the content, the search is able to return document ID and other informations like subject, author, date, etc. However, the content of the document is not shown.

This is what I got from the result.

If I didn't request the content field in the `fl` parameters, this is what I got:

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0,
    "params": {
      "indent": "true",
      "q": "*:*",
      "_": "1425362114731",
      "wt": "json"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 2,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "id": "C:\\Users\\GHI\\solr-5.0.0\\example\\exampledocs\\solr-word.pdf",
        "meta_save_date": [
          "2008-11-13T00:00:00Z"
        ],
        "dc_subject": [
          "solr, word, pdf"
        ],
        "subject": [
          "solr word"
        ],
        "author": [
          "Grant Ingersoll"
        ],
        "dcterms_created": [
          "2008-11-13T00:00:00Z"
        ],
        "date": [
          "2008-11-13T00:00:00Z"
        ],
        "creator": [
          "Grant Ingersoll"
        ],
        "creation_date": [
          "2008-11-13T00:00:00Z"
        ],
        "title": [
          "solr-word"
        ],
        "meta_author": [
          "Grant Ingersoll"
        ],
        "stream_content_type": [
          "application/pdf"
        ],
        "created": [
          "Thu Nov 13 13:35:51 UTC 2008"
        ],
        "stream_size": [
          21052
        ],
        "meta_keyword": [
          "solr, word, pdf"
        ],
        "cp_subject": [
          "solr word"
        ],
        "dc_format": [
          "application/pdf; version=1.3"
        ],
        "xmp_creatortool": [
          "Microsoft Word"
        ],
        "resourcename": [
          "C:\\Users\\GHI\\solr-5.0.0\\example\\exampledocs\\solr-word.pdf"
        ],
        "keywords": [
          "solr, word, pdf"
        ],
        "last_save_date": [
          "2008-11-13T00:00:00Z"
        ],
        "dc_title": [
          "solr-word"
        ],
        "dcterms_modified": [
          "2008-11-13T00:00:00Z"
        ],
        "meta_creation_date": [
          "2008-11-13T00:00:00Z"
        ],
        "dc_creator": [
          "Grant Ingersoll"
        ],
        "pdf_pdfversion": [
          1.3
        ],
        "last_modified": [
          "2008-11-13T00:00:00Z"
        ],
        "aapl_keywords": [
          "solr, word, pdf"
        ],
        "x_parsed_by": [
          "org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser"
        ],
        "modified": [
          "2008-11-13T00:00:00Z"
        ],
        "xmptpg_npages": [
          1
        ],
        "pdf_encrypted": [
          false
        ],
        "producer": [
          "Mac OS X 10.5.5 Quartz PDFContext"
        ],
        "content_type": [
          "application/pdf"
        ],
        "_version_": 1494155334466404300
      },
      {
        "id": "C:\\Users\\GHI\\solr-5.0.0\\example\\exampledocs\\solr-word2.pdf",
        "meta_save_date": [
          "2015-02-25T00:00:00Z"
        ],
        "author": [
          "GHI"
        ],
        "dcterms_created": [
          "2015-02-25T00:00:00Z"
        ],
        "date": [
          "2015-02-25T00:00:00Z"
        ],
        "creator": [
          "GHI"
        ],
        "creation_date": [
          "2015-02-25T00:00:00Z"
        ],
        "title": [
          "This is another test of PDF extraction in Solr"
        ],
        "meta_author": [
          "GHI"
        ],
        "stream_content_type": [
          "application/pdf"
        ],
        "created": [
          "Wed Feb 25 08:32:19 UTC 2015"
        ],
        "stream_size": [
          10345
        ],
        "dc_format": [
          "application/pdf; version=1.4"
        ],
        "xmp_creatortool": [
          "PDFCreator Version 1.3.2"
        ],
        "resourcename": [
          "C:\\Users\\GHI\\solr-5.0.0\\example\\exampledocs\\solr-word2.pdf"
        ],
        "last_save_date": [
          "2015-02-25T00:00:00Z"
        ],
        "dc_title": [
          "This is another test of PDF extraction in Solr"
        ],
        "dcterms_modified": [
          "2015-02-25T00:00:00Z"
        ],
        "meta_creation_date": [
          "2015-02-25T00:00:00Z"
        ],
        "dc_creator": [
          "GHI"
        ],
        "pdf_pdfversion": [
          1.4
        ],
        "last_modified": [
          "2015-02-25T00:00:00Z"
        ],
        "x_parsed_by": [
          "org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser"
        ],
        "modified": [
          "2015-02-25T00:00:00Z"
        ],
        "xmptpg_npages": [
          1
        ],
        "pdf_encrypted": [
          false
        ],
        "producer": [
          "GPL Ghostscript 9.05"
        ],
        "content_type": [
          "application/pdf"
        ],
        "_version_": 1494155342991327200
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If I request for the content field in the `fl` parameters, this is what I got.

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 1,
    "params": {
      "fl": "content",
      "indent": "true",
      "q": "*:*",
      "_": "1425362147661",
      "wt": "json"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 2,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {},
      {}
    ]
  }
}
```

If I do a query like `q=content:[* TO *]&fl=id,content`

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":5,
    "params":{
      "fl":"id,content",
      "q":"content:[* TO *]"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  }
}
```

I'm able to get it to work in Solr 4.10.1, but it's not working in Solr 5.0. Is there anything that I need to take note for Solr 5.0 which is different from the previous versions of Solr?

Answer (score 2):

I've only worked with Solr version 5 and above but hope this helps: in order to a field to be searchable it must be of type "text". For example if you have a set of fields like:

```
   <field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="author" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="keywords" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="resourcename" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="url" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="content_type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

And you want them to be searchable you must add the correspondent copy fields to text.

```
   <copyField source="title" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="author" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="description" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="keywords" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="content" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="content_type" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="resourcename" dest="text"/>
   <copyField source="url" dest="text"/>
```